# Discord bot responds multiple times for one event

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to respond once to a command such as `.on`.  However, it responds multiple times per input:

[image: screenshot]

The code is:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.content === '.on'){
        message.channel.sendMessage('Testing Bot is now Online, Greetings, ' + message.author.username);
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction to make the bot respond once that would be great.

Comment: Here is the answer on Duplicated question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064042/discord-bot-still-answering-multiple-times-on-one-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064042/discord-bot-still-answering-multiple-times-on-one-event)

Comment: Extra points for Trump bot

Answer (score 0):

`sendMessage` is [deprecated](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage). Try using [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) instead.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '.on') {
        message.channel.send('Testing Bot is now Online, Greetings, ' + message.author.username);
    }
}
```

Also, if this still causes issues consider checking the id/content of the message event as well as the returned promise to make sure you didn't make a mistake elsewhere. It'll be obvious very quickly what's going on. That'd be:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '.on') {
        console.log('Received #' + message.id + ': ' + message.content);
        message.channel.send('Testing Bot is now Online, Greetings, ' + message.author.username)
        .then(message => console.log('Sent #' + message.id + ': ' + message.content))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but I think you had multiple [instances](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/16325/instance) of your bot running at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the token, so all bots will stop working and then make sure, you just starting one instance.

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit more detail?