# Discord bot still answering multiple times on one event

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Already found [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772293/discord-bot-responds-multiple-times-for-one-event), but there are no answer there :C

So my problem is same, using Discord.js lib, and this is my code:

```
 client.on('message', msg => {
     var splittedMessage = msg.content.split("#");
     if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
         if (msg.content === "booya") {
             msg.channel.send('Hello there, ' + msg.author.username)
                 .then(msg => console.log('Sent #' + msg.id + ': ' + msg.content))
                 .catch(console.error);
             return
         } else {
             msg.channel.send('No query found')
                 .then(msg => console.log('Sent #' + msg.id + ': ' + msg.content))
                 .catch(console.error);
             return
         }
     }
 });
```

And here is result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8XKS.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible that `client.on('message')` also gets called for the messages the bot itself sends? Have you tried `console.log(message)` to see what's going on?

Comment: @AKX for example, this code is working fine only one time: [https://pastebin.com/3e9K6S16](https://pastebin.com/3e9K6S16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `message` is triggered on all messages, even the ones the bot sends :

> Emitted whenever a message is created.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message

So you are continually triggering the event by sending a message.

The solution is to always check for the author, if it is different than the bot itself (the bot-user property is `bot.user` : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=user)

Answer (score 0):

First if you are using Visual Studio Code you can run multiple instances of the same program/bot.
the terminal in Visual Studio Code:
[image: the terminal in Visual Studio Code]

So each time you edit then start the script it will create a "new" terminal (so another instance). where these instances are located:
[image: where these instances are located]

So then press the recycle button (next to the drop down menu) on all of the instances. Then start the script again - it should be fine.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)